# Xna: drawing dynamics alpha map

Tags: c#, graphics, xna

I need to draw simple alpha maps in xna which depends on current game state. I cannot save many kinds of alpha maps in reseources, so i want to draw them dynamically.

For example sprite can be partially hidden behind wall.

I think about using System.Drawing, but when i'm including this dll, there are conflicts with Xna namespaces. Is there another way to draw simple bitmaps in xna?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you think of any other cases that require you to generate the alpha map dynamically? Partially obscured sprites can be as simple as drawing the sprites in different layers (with or without the depth buffer). A great many things are possible using graphics API that might be be intuitive at first. It might be that there's an easier way to do what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the System.Drawing classes. These work on images that lie in the system RAM. Instead use XNA to manipulate a texture that lies in GPU memory.

You can use [SetRenderTarget()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434434%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) to set the texture as the render target. This will cause further draw calls to be executed on the texture. This way, you can draw everything on the texture. However, you will not have methods for drawing circles, squares etc. To achieve this, you should either create vertex buffers with the according geometry or use a sprite template.

Comment: You have paid my attention to important thing: drawing it on GPU. Thank you.